# how to start and check job history on hadoop 2.5.2

Tags: hadoop

1. in the mapreduce webconsole for each application there is a tracking ui link which points to xx:19888/jobhistory/, but how to start the service on 19888 (i have started 4 services: yarn-resource-manager, yarn-node-manager, hdfs-name-node, hdfs-data-node, what i have missed?)
2. is the jobtracker removed in 2.5.2
3. I want to check the job.xml generated for my job, where can i find it. I have specified "mapreduce.jobtracker.jobhistory.location" but nothing is there

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try 'jps' command to verify all the services are running.

try  //jhs_host:port/   Default HTTP port is 19888."

Make sure that your hadoop services are running.

Comment: the service on 19888 is not running, which command can start the service listening on that, i am using 2.5.2,
the jps result is following:
`
13780 Jps
35256 ResourceManager
14100 NodeManager
55528 NameNode
54500 DataNode
`
Thanks

Comment: to start the historyserver 

$>start mapred historyserver

Answer (score 6):

1. To access the JobHistory server's web interface then you have start the `hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver` service, which will bind to `19888` by default.
2. If your are running YARN in the cluster then you don't need jobtracker anymore, the work done jobtracker is offloaded to ResourceManager, NodeManager's & ApplicationMaster's. But, you could still install just MRv1 in that case you will install JobTracker and TaskTracker's (which is not recommended).
3. You could check the job.xml from the ResourceManager's UI by navigating to `http://RESOURCEMANAGER_HOST:8088/cluster` -> select your application's *Tracking UI* -> Select your *Job ID* -> On the left tab you'll be able to see *Configuration*. Or simply if you already know you'r job's id then visit this link: `http://JOBHISTORY_SERVER:19888/jobhistory/conf/YOUR_JOB_ID`.

Comment: i have started 4 services: yarn-resource-manager, yarn-node-manager, hdfs-name-node, hdfs-data-node.
but it tells me the 19888 port has not service listened on. what else service I need to start, is it the ApplicationMaster you mentioned? Thanks Ashrith.

Comment: You have to configure and start `hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver` service. Use this apache [guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html) to do so.

Answer (score 4):

$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop start historyserver

then run jps to see if it is running.