# I cannot see the running applications in hadoop 2.5.2 (yarn)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I installed hadoop 2.5.2, and I can run the wordcount sample successfully. However, when I want to see the application running on yarn (job running), I cannot as all applictaions interface is always empty (shown in the following screen).
Is there anyway to make the jobs visible?
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try localhost:19888 or check value of the the property for web url for job history (mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address) configured in you yarn config file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; however, I got an error once I tried "localhost:19888". It says :"Sorry you got an error 500, please consult RFC 2616..". On the other hand, I don't have the property for we url for job history in my yarn-site.xml configuration

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174593/how-to-start-and-check-job-history-on-hadoop-2-5-2

Comment: Sorry, I can display the interface but I cannot see the jobs running; although they were successful.